# Push from a local repo directly to a new machine

Tags: git

I have a git project on my machine, and I am trying to set it up to push directly (without involving github, bitbucket etc.) to a repo on a different machine. I cannot reverse the process and simply run `git clone` from the remote, because I have no sshd on my own machine.

I have told my local repo about the new remote:

```
git remote add deploy ssh://different.machine//path/to/repo/.git
```

But **how do I set up the new remote to receive the changes?**

- If I create an empty remote with `git init --bare`, I can push all my changes but `git checkout master` fails on the remote machine with the message "fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree".
- If I create an empty remote with `git init`, the command `git push --all deploy` fails:

  ```
  Enumerating objects: 51, done.
  Counting objects: 100% (51/51), done.
  Delta compression using up to 4 threads
  Compressing objects: 100% (29/29), done.
  Writing objects: 100% (51/51), 73.03 KiB | 73.03 MiB/s, done.
  Total 51 (delta 21), reused 51 (delta 21)
  remote: error: refusing to update checked out branch: refs/heads/master
  remote: error: By default, updating the current branch in a non-bare repository
  remote: error: is denied, because it will make the index and work tree inconsistent
  remote: error: with what you pushed, and will require 'git reset --hard' to match
  remote: error: the work tree to HEAD.
  remote: error: 
  remote: error: You can set 'receive.denyCurrentBranch' configuration variable t
  remote: error: 'ignore' or 'warn' in the remote repository to allow pushing int
  remote: error: its current branch; however, this is not recommended unless ETC...
  ```

Well, what is the *recommended* way to do this? I don't want to go tweaking "not recommended" settings that I do not understand and that will cause me more troubles down the line.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Are you trying to *do work* in both repositories? Or is the remote one "just" used to store stuff (i.e. push/pull from/to)? If it's the latter, then you want a bare repository, if it's the former then you're trying to run an unsupported configuration and will have a bad time.

Answer (score 2):

> If I create an empty remote with `git init --bare`, I can push all my changes but git checkout master fails on the remote machine with the message `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`.

Lets break it into small pieces and explain wha is going on one by one.

#### `git init --bare`

When you run `git init <optional folder name>` git will create a new folder and will initialize the folder with a `.git` folder, without getting into too many details, this folder contains the **"metadata"** for git to operate and the folder itself is you "worktree".

[image]

When you run `git init --bare` git does not create `.git` folder, instead of having the content inside the `.git` folder, the content of that folder is in your current folder. This is the meaning of `bare`, you have a bare repository without working tree.

---

> I can push all my changes

The bare repository contains all your branches, tags, notes, etc. The "data" is stored in the Objects folder along with the pack's file.

---

> `git checkout master` fails on the remote machine with the message `fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree`.

As explained above - in a brea repository you don't have worktree so you cant checkout content.

---

#### What can you do?

Git support several transfers protocol for connecting between repositories. So you can use the `file` protocol to create a working repository on your remote machine.

```
# Clone the bare repo to a new folder
git clone /usr/folder/.../.git
```

#### Worktree

Another solution is to use `git worktree`.
`git worktrtee` will create a worktree from your bare repository so you will be able to work

```sh
###
### Creating new worktree
###

### create new branch inside the worktree folder 
git worktree -b <branch name> <path>

# Or (branch name can be exiting branch or new one)
git worktree add <path>/<branch name>
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! Now I understand why I had to add ".git" to the path when I was trying to clone with `--bare`. What I still don't understand is, if my bare clone is located at `path/name/.git`, what `worktree` command will put the sources in `path/name`? And can I use `git worktree` to convert a bare repo to something that I can manage like an ordinary code base, but that I can push to? Or (as it seems now) is that simply out of the question?

Answer (score 1):

You've forgotten to explain how are you going to use the repository on the different machine.

Without better understanding of your needs the general recommended way is to use an intermediate bare repository and the final non-bare. It doesn't matter where the  intermediate bare repository is — a git hosting or a  bare repo at the different machine.

You push to the intermediate bare repository and clone/pull from it to the non-bare. You can automate the process by adding a `post-receive`/`post-update` hook to the bare repo.

Let's create both repositories at the single remote host:

```
ssh user@remote-host "
cd /some/path/ &&
git init --bare myrepo.git &&
git clone myrepo.git myrepo &&
echo '#!/bin/sh

for ref in "$@"; do
   if [ "$ref" = refs/heads/master ]; then
      unset GIT_DIR
      cd ../myrepo &&
      exec git pull ../myrepo.git master
   fi
done' > myrepo.git/hooks/post-update &&
chmod a+x myrepo.git/hooks/post-update
"

cd /path/to/local-repo &&
git remote add remote-repo user@remote-repo:/some/path/myrepo.git
git push remote-repo master
```

Comment: My goal is to deploy updates using `git push` (since network issues prevent running `git pull` on the remote server.)

Comment: Thanks for the script! I get the general idea of pushing to a bare repo and cloning from it to a full repo. But what is the magic carried out by the `for` loop? What does it accomplish and why is it necessary? And what arguments (cf. `$@`) should the script be called with? Please explain.

Comment: It looks like the post-update hook propagates changes from the bare to the regular repo, but I cannot tell when it fires (or why a for-loop is involved).

Comment: [`post-update` hook](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#post-update) is invoked by `git push` at the server side. It's passed a number of parameters, each of which is the name of ref that was actually updated. As you only need to pull one branch (`master` in my script but adapt to your needs) the script needs a loop to test if the parameter is there.